# Texture is stretched on certain faces

Tags: texturing

I'm currently modeling a football stadium, applying a texture to the stairs I created using the array modifier from a simple cube shape.

When I apply a texture to the stairs, the texture is clear on the flat part of the step, but the front of the step is stretching the texture horizontally, and does't look like the concrete surface I'm trying to achieve. Does anyone know an easy solution to this issue?[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show you work with a Blender screen capture.  Please do this consistently for all future questions.   Your words and a carefully considered image will clarify your question.

Comment: sounds like you did not unwrapped the mesh correctly. Apply scale and then unwrap again.

Comment: Sorry... I'm new to all of this. I've placed the images in the post

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your node tree this is my best guess. Under the texture image node change the projection from flat to box. You can also change the blend value but if your stairs are perpendicular it probably won't change anything

Edit: sorry picture is sideways i am on my phone.

[image: Node Info]

Comment: For reference, this might provide a way of taking slightly higher quality screenshots: https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/

Comment: Its a photo of my computer screen, taken on my phone, as I was replying via the app

Answer (score 0):

In you node tree we can see you're using the box projection while using the UV coordinates. Most of the time it doesn't work that way.

Either you use the UV coordinates and you set the textures to flat projection:
[image: UV coordinates and Flat projection]

Either you use any other texture coordinate (usually generated) and any projection you want:
[image: Generated coordinates and Box projection]

It's important to note a few other things:

- You must have even scales on your object, meaning the scale of your objects should always be the exact same value on each axis, and ideally equal to 1.
  If you don't have even scales, select your object in object mode and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> → apply scale.
- For using UV coordinates, [you must have unwrapped your object](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/uv_image/uv/editing/unwrapping/index.html).